# Proving a particular inequality using Hölder

Tags: inequality, holder-inequality

I'm reading *An Introduction to Inequalities* by Beckenbach and the following inequality is left as an exercise for the reader ( Chapter 6, p. 104) :
$$[|x|^n + |y|^n]^{1/n} \geq [|x|^m + |y|^m]^{1/m} $$
for all rational $m \geq n \geq 1$. The book states that it can be proven using Hölder's inequality, but I'm having some difficulty doing so.

My attempt is as follows:

\begin{equation*}
|x| = a \; ; \; |y| = b\\
(a^n + b^n)^{1/n} \geq (a^m + b^m)^{1/m}\\
\end{equation*}

Using Hölder we get

$$(a^n + b^n)^{1/n} \cdot (a^m + b^m)^{1/m} \geq a^{n+m}\, + \, b^{n+m} $$
However I don't quite see what I  should do after this. I also tried:

$$(a+b) \cdot (a^{n} + b^{n} )^{1/n} \geq a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}$$
And since $a+b \leq a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}$

$$(a^{n+1}+b^{n+1})(a^{n} + b^{n} )^{1/n} \geq a^{n+1}+b^{n+1} \implies (a^{n} + b^{n} )^{1/n} \geq 1 $$
Doing the same thing for $(a+b)\cdot(a^{m}+b^{m})^{1/m} \geq a^{m+1} + b^{m+1}$ we obtain

$$(a^m+b^m)^{1/m} \geq 1$$
Adding both inequalities

$$(a^n+b^n)^{1/n} \;+\; (a^m+b^m)^{1/m} \geq 2$$
And once again I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Remember that Holder requires $1/p + 1/q = 1$. Can you state the $p, q$ that you used?  EG Are you assuming that $ 1/n + 1/m = 1$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I am assuming that $1/n + 1/m = 1$, yes. My idea is to make $p = n$ and $q = m$.

Comment: That's not a valid assumption. EG With $ n  =1, m = 2$, that equation doesn't hold. What you need to do, is to tweak it such that you have corresponding $p, q$ values that work. As a hint, try $ p = m/n$ (so $1/p = n/m < 1$ and we can find a corresponding $q$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $m\geq n \geq 1$ are rational, then there are integers $p,q,r,t\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, such that $m=p/q, n=r/t$. Thus, the inequality can be rewritten as
$$
\left(a^{p/q}+b^{p/q}\right)^{\frac{1}{pt}} \leq \left(a^{r/t}+b^{r/t}\right)^{\frac{1}{qr}},
$$
and by making the variable substitutions $a \mapsto a^{qt}, b\mapsto b^{qt},$ then the inequality becomes
$$
\left(a^{pt}+b^{pt}\right)^{\frac{1}{pt}} \leq \left(a^{qr}+b^{qr}\right)^{\frac{1}{qr}},
$$
so we can assume w.l.o.g. that $m,n$ are positive integers.

Now, the case $m=n$ is obvious, and the case $m>n=1$ is also easy to prove by expanding $(a+b)^m$.

So, assume as inductive hypothesis that the inequality holds for $m-1 > n-1 >1$ for all $a,b$ nonnegative, then using Hölder's inquality and the inductive hypothesis:
$$a^m + b^m = aa^{m-1}+bb^{m-1}\leq \left(a^n + b^n\right)^{1/n}\left(a^{(m-1)\frac{n}{n-1}} + b^{(m-1)\frac{n}{n-1}}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{n}} \leq \left(a^n + b^n\right)^{1/n}\left(a^{(n-1)\frac{n}{n-1}}+b^{(n-1)\frac{n}{n-1}}\right)^{\frac{(m-1)(n-1)}{n(n-1)}} = \left(a^n + b^n\right)^{m/n},$$
thus, the inequality is proven by induction.

The same technique can be used for any number of variables, and the inequality can be extended to real $m,n$, by taking rational sequences that converge, and using the continuity of $f(t) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^t\right)^{1/t}$.